# azure data factory - salesforce lookup

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory

I am utilizing azure data factory upsert salesforce.
I have two tables in salesforce
contacts__c  (holds the the individual first and last name )
contactdetails__c  (holds additional information about contact)

since I can not use dataflows directly with salesforce (for lookup), I upsert contact__c (sourcesystemid__c  hold our internal contact ID).

when trying upsert  contactdetails__c, I have to perform a lookup on the fly to know the salesforce internal ID associated for each contact and use that to upsert contactdetails__c.

I saw article suggesting to use contact__r.sourcesystemid__c which doesn't work for me .

I use copy data activity for contactdetails with source being my data in azure sql (with our internal contact ID) and sink is contactdetails__c on the mapping of the contactID I use

source                                      sink

---

contactid                                  contact__r.sourcesystemid__c

but it doesn't work
would appreciate any suggestion as to how I can lookup internal id of contact while  upserting contactdetails table
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing a lot of details. I do not know how you are trying to do this, but assuming you are using the REST API then take a look at the section named **Upserting Records and Associating with an External ID** of [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm).

One question... Why are you using custom sObjects for this? Why not use the standard Contact sObject. Also having the data denormalized like you are indicating is a bad idea in Salesforce.